# What are some potential reasons why this LVP is buckling?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

3 years old LVP, TrafficMaster's Edwards Oaks. I have never seen LVP buckle like this. I found an extra underlayment underneath. Do you think it could be because the extra layer of underlayment made the floor extra bouncy to walk and that caused the planks to shift back and forth, causing buckling?

[image]

Comment: Either high moisture or a non flat sub floor or a mixture of the two.  The broken piece looks like the sub floor was not flat(within 2/16).

Comment: A too-thick underlay or multiple layers of underlay that are squishy will cause too much flex and cause cracking etc. Always check the LVP manufacturer specifications for underlayment.

Comment: Could be negligent installation. The joints are click-lock, no? I can imagine screwing up the end laps to cause something like that. I think I see cupping. I could see cupping from the hardwood click lock stuff. Is there a wood substrate under an upper shell of vinyl in that flooring or something? Last stuff I saw was plastic all the way through, I thought.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? The flooring was obviously not installed correctly, so tear it out and follow the manufacturer's advice when you put new flooring in. Anything we'd say is a guess.

Comment: The flooring was not installed incorrectly. It is laminate that has been exposed to water.  The orange big box store carries tons of "TrafficMaster" flooring that is laminate.  the pictures show proof the floor is laminate with curled ends and cracked top layer, that simply cannot happen with LVP flooring.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is NOT LVP it is Laminate and has been exposed to water.

The blue padding shown is common for laminate installations and LVP does not delaminate and degrade like what is shown in the pictures.

Laminate flooring that has been exposed to water does **exactly** what your picture shows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get it, I don't use laminate. It is LVP, it's the traffic master stuff from home depot. The underlayment is from laminate that was thrown out, I guess the handyman did not remove the underlayment.